# Most efficient way to clear a named graph?

Tags: sparql, graphdb, rdf4j, named-graphs

I am working with an instance of Ontotext GraphDB and often want to clear a named graph with a large number of triples.

Currently, my technique involves issuing a SPARQL command to the graph server, which searches and matches a triple pattern of every triple in the named graph:

```
DELETE { GRAPH example:exampleGraph { ?s ?p ?o }} WHERE {?s ?p ?o .}
```

When there are a lot of triples, this approach often takes quite some time to clear the named graph.

I am wondering whether there is a more efficient way to do this. Even a triplestore-specific solution would be acceptable to me.

I should also note that I am using the RDF4J library to communicate with the graph. I understand that certain solutions may work on the Ontotext web interface, but I am only interested in a solution which I can implement programatically.

Comment: The might be no difference regarding performance, but [`CLEAR`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#clear) is the dedicated command from the SPARQL 1.1 Update specs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the SPARQL [CLEAR](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#clear) command for this:

```
CLEAR GRAPH example:exampleGraph
```

Or alternatively, [DROP](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#drop):

```
DROP GRAPH example:exampleGraph
```

The difference between the two is that `CLEAR` allows triplestores to keep an empty named graph, while the `DROP` completely removes the named graph. But in the case of GraphDB there's no practical difference as GraphDB never keeps a reference to an empty named graph.

If you don't want to use SPARQL, you can use the [RDF4J API](http://docs.rdf4j.org/programming/) to programmatically call the `clear()` operation:

```java
IRI graph = graphdb.getValueFactory().createIRI("http://example.org/exampleGraph");  
try(RepositoryConnection conn = graphdb.getConnection()) {
   conn.clear(graph);
}
```

or more succinctly:

```java
IRI graph = graphdb.getValueFactory().createIRI("http://example.org/exampleGraph");  
Repositories.consume(graphdb, conn -> conn.clear(graph));
```

Comment: Thanks! I switched my code to use CLEAR GRAPH and the performance is much better.