# Clearing a named graph in GraphDB free is slow

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, graphdb, rdf4j, named-graphs

Clearing a named graph with many triples through rdf4j with clear(context) function is slow.
Even, manually deleting a named graph through the graphdb interface http://localhost:7200/graphs is slow.
I tried to play with the JVM memory according to those [guidelines](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/8.10/free/configuring-a-repository.html). My server has 64GB RAM, and I am calling graphdb with 40GB JVM memory, the 'graphdb.page.cache.size' is being set to default value '17.8G'  :

```
./graphdb -Xnx40g
```

but there is no improvement in time when clearing a named graph. It takes approximately 40sec.

Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to clear a named graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280986/most-efficient-way-to-clear-a-named-graph)

Comment: I think the TO is already using `clear graph` or `drop graph` but it's just slow?

Comment: Unfortunately https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280986/most-efficient-way-to-clear-a-named-graph did not help. I tried clear, delete and drop, but performance did not  get improved.

Comment: Is the context index enabled on your repository? See http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/storage.html

Comment: I see a 'context index' option in the setting of repository. I checked it, but I do not see any improvement in performance.

Comment: I read here http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/delete-optimisations.html that delete of triples takes time, because inferred statements are also checked. But I do not know what I should do for accelerate the delete operation's time.

Comment: 1. Is the context index enabled? If not, it has to check every quad in the repo. 2. Ensure your ontologies are inserted as part of "systemTransaction". 3. Do you use some reasoning you don't really need? https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/rules-optimisations.html#hints-on-optimizing-graphdb-s-rulesets